# Cant seem to align logo with navbar

Tags: css, menu, navigation, alignment, graphical-logo

I am fairly new to web development and I have been trying to create a site, so far I have managed to do a navigation menu and a logo. My issue is that after thoroughly trying many tutorials and posts I have been unable to resolve my issue.
I want to align my logo with my navbar so that the logo is on the left hand side and the navbar is in line with the logo but on the right hand side, with both of them next to each other. 
next questions is how to create a drop down menu for some of navbar tabs?
thankyou

My html is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>S3ntry Aust Transport</title>
<link href="navbarlog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="Layout1" style="overflow: auto; ">
<header>
<div id="menu">
<img src="logo.JPG" style="float: left; " alt="logo" name="logo" width="571" 

height="176" id="logo"></a>
</div>
</header>
<ul>
<li><a id="nav-index" class="first" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="nav-aboutus" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">About Us</a></li>
<li><a id="nav-ourservices" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Our Services</a></li>
<li><a id="nav-environment" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Environment</a></li>
<li><a id="nav-latestnews" href="#">Latest News</a></li>
<li><a id="nav-contactus" class="last" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css part is as follows

```
ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0 auto; width:640px; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}li     
{float:left;}
ul li a {display:block; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; padding:22px 20px 22px   
20px;font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; text-  
transform:uppercase; border-right:1px solid #607987; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-
transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:.08em}
ul li a:hover {background-color:#3b6a85; color:#a2becf}
ul li a.first {border-left:0}
ul li a.last {border-right:0}}

#header ul li {
list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
float:right
} 

logo.JPG 
{
vertical-align:middle;
float:left
}
```

Comment: Re-name your `logo.JPG` in the CSS to `.logo` and then edit the image wrapper to `<img src="logo.JPG" style="float: left; " alt="logo" name="logo" width="571" height="176" id="logo" class="logo">`. Does this solve any problems? As a side-note but not really related, remove `</a>` from the code, there's no beginning to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to restructure your HTML, moving your 'ul' into the header, it's very easy.

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="logo.JPG" style="float: left; " alt="logo" name="logo" width="571" height="176" id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="nav-index" class="first"   href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-aboutus" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-ourservices" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-environment" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Environment</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-latestnews" href="#">Latest News</a></li>
            <li><a id="nav-contactus" class="last" href="%E2%80%9D#%E2%80%9D">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</header>
```

and the CSS needed

```
header { width: 700px; }

#logo { float: left; }

#menu { float: right; }
#menu ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/STu89/

I've also removed a  which wasn't opened and stripped out various /div which weren't matched.

Comment: you have two `#logo` ids in your HTML